# Ansible Windows - Copying within remote

Tags: windows, ansible

I am trying to use Ansible to copy from one location on a server to another location on the same server, e.g. "cp c:/users/foo c:/users/bar" but cannot find how to do so, or even if it is possible.

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not sure what use case you have that has a file on a remote that needs to be copied to a different place but that file cannot exist on the Ansible host. Can you elaborate?

Comment: @ydaetskcoR we are are booting ec2 instances meant for specific people on a domain, the main use case is copying the admin user folder and then renaming it to the domain user

Comment: I would put that folder on S3 and take it from there with win_get_url or with some powershell

Answer (score 1):

Use `remote_src: True`

*Example:*

```
- name: Copy a single file where the source is on the remote host
  win_copy:
    src: C:\temp\foo.txt
    dest: C:\ansible\foo.txt
    remote_src: True
```

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/win_copy_module.html

Comment: He wants to copy files on the same server, why would he want to use remote copy?

Comment: This is the correct answer. `win_copy` with paramter `remote_src: True`.

Comment: This worked. Better if you can update the format of this answer. (Ex: Use a separate section for code lines).
Edit: updated.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "raw" module and send your command directelly to Powershell:

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/raw_module.html

Despite it's description, it can be used for windows.

Sérgio